# Other way of finding a running application without using windowname, proc name pid or path

Tags: c#

Is there any other way of finding if a certain application is running without looking for it using the window name,process name, pid or path?

There would be another way by using the windowclass name but there are plenty of processes which could use the defined class and it may fall into false detection.On the other hand I can get the parent window of the process who's using the defined class and look for some controls name but this is also not suitable because there could be a lot of processes to check if they use the same classname.

Comment: Do you need to find your own application or is it *any* application you want to find? If it's your own, you can communicate without enumerating windows, using mutexes for simple binary tasks (another one started or not) or other forms of interprocess communication.

Comment: No, its not my application .

Comment: Answer on a question "how I can tell what it is this application I am searching for" and you are done. There can be something unique to the application, but you have to find it. Example, application may be always installed into a folder `bin`, have certain `dll`'s inside it and there is always `data` folder near `bin` - so you can identify it now, right?

Comment: The b.files can be taken from the bin folder and I'm talking about applications who are not using dlls in order to execute smth so this won't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about looking at it with process explorer and seeing if it creates any Events, Mutexes etc and if you can find one that is unique to the application you may be able to via that method.

Maybe it opens a lock on a file. You could open a filesystem watcher looking at that file for modification/creation etc.

Comment: I will try looking at that but generally the application will send some data to a client. ( for example a game client and a application for auto attacking )